# How to create a wildcard to deny all requests from all ips in AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, web-application-firewall

I got a microservice in an ECS instance in AWS behind a WAF, I want to create these rules:

1. Allow specific IPs (done)
2. Allow all connections from inside the VPN (done)
3. Deny all the other requests.

The first two IP set are created, but I can't make the last one to work. I tried creating the IP set with `0.0.0.0/0` and another combinations without success.

This is my code, I removed ipset 1 and 2 (that are working), this is the ipset 3:

```
resource "aws_wafv2_ip_set" "ipset" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-${var.environment_name}-whitelist-ips"

  scope              = "REGIONAL"
  ip_address_version = "IPV4"

  addresses = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

module "alb_wafv2" {
  source = "trussworks/wafv2/aws"
  version = "~> 2.0"

  name = "${var.app_name}-${var.environment_name}"
  scope = "REGIONAL"
  alb_arn = aws_lb.app_lb.arn
  associate_alb = true

  ip_sets_rule = [
    {
      name       = "${var.app_name}-${var.environment_name}-ip-blacklist"
      action     = "deny"
      priority   = 1
      ip_set_arn = aws_wafv2_ip_set.ipset.arn
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  RespMetadata: {
    StatusCode: 400,
    RequestID: "c98b2d3a-ebd0-44e0-a80a-702bc698598b"
  },
  Field: "IP_ADDRESS",
  Message_: "Error reason: The parameter contains formatting that is not valid., field: IP_ADDRESS, parameter: 0.0.0.0/0",
  Parameter: "0.0.0.0/0",
  Reason: "The parameter contains formatting that is not valid."
}
```

Tried to create an IP Set from the AWS Console with the same error:
[image: AWS console]

So I got two questions, first, how can I do this? And the second one, is this the best approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I tried creating " - can you show actual code that you tried with error messages?

Comment: My bad, I added the actual code and the output @Marcin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to block 0.0.0.0/0. After you created two IP rules, look "**Default web ACL action for requests that don't match any rules**" on WAF console and set Action to Block.

Comment: This should not work if you add also AWSManaged rules to your WebACL. Isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

Consider using this trick to bypass the 0.0.0.0/0 limitation:
Divide the IPv4 address space into two chunks: [0.0.0.0/1](https://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html?cclass=any&csubnet=1&cip=0.0.0.0&ctype=ipv4&printit=0&x=63&y=24) and 128.0.0.0/1

The following terraform snippet was accepted and the ip set was created by TF (Terraform 0.15.4 and aws provider version 3.42.0):

```
resource "aws_wafv2_ip_set" "ipset" {
  name = "all_internet_kludge"

  scope              = "REGIONAL"
  ip_address_version = "IPV4"

  addresses = ["0.0.0.0/1", "128.0.0.0/1"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't block all addresses (CIDR /0). It is **not supported**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-ipset.html#cfn-wafv2-ipset-addresses):

> AWS WAF supports all IPv4 and IPv6 CIDR ranges **except for /0**.

Instead, you can use network ACL to deny all traffic, or security groups.

Comment: I ended setting up the default action to "block", thanks a lot for your help